# openSUSE and log4cxx

Tags: ros, log4cxx, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install ROS on a Lenovo X200 Tablet running openSUSE 11.3. I've been through a few iterations already trying to make sure that I have all the dependencies in order, etc. I'm following [the instructions on the ROS website](http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/OpenSUSE) to the letter.

Versions:
gcc: 4.5.0
cmake: 2.8.1
Python: 2.6.5

I'm at the stage where I use **rosinstall** to download and install everything. Here's the command I've been using: **rosinstall ~/ros "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=diamondback&variant=desktop-full&overlay=no"**

Things only seem to go awry with regard to the packages, so that's the output I will include here:

#Packages
sudo zypper install python-yaml log4cxx-devel
}}}
Retrieving repository 'Updates for openSUSE 11.3 11.3-1.82' metadata [done]
Building repository 'Updates for openSUSE 11.3 11.3-1.82' cache [done]
Retrieving repository 'devel:languages:python:Factory' metadata [done]
Building repository 'devel:languages:python:Factory' cache [done]
Retrieving repository 'devel:libraries:c_c++' metadata [done]
Building repository 'devel:libraries:c_c++' cache [done]
Retrieving repository 'google-chrome' metadata [done]
Building repository 'google-chrome' cache [done]
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'log4cxx-devel' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.
[ rosmake ] rosdep install failed: rosdep script failed with stderr 
{{{
Package 'python' not found.
No provider of 'log4cxx-devel' found.

}}} 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/rosinstall", line 5, in < module >
pkg_resources.run_script('rosinstall==0.5.16', 'rosinstall')
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 489, in run_script
self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1214, in run_script
exec script_code in namespace, namespace
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 556, in < module >

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 547, in rosinstall_main

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 498, in check_call
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'source /root/ros/setup.sh && rosmake ros ros_comm --rosdep-install' returned non-zero exit status 1

I'm not sure that anything else would be much help, but let me know and I will provide what I can. I've been looking for log4cxx to install it manually, either from a package or from a source, but with no luck either way. Thanks for any help you can offer!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10032/opensuse-and-log4cxx/) by [teddybouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/581/teddybouch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 320 on 2011-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Alright, I think that I have it figured out. I'll amend this post if I try the tutorials and something breaks, but for now rosinstall completed successfully.

It turns out that there are dependency conflicts in a number of the modules that ROS uses. For instance, mercurial requires python=2.6, but python-setuptools requires python=2.7. My solution was to install Python 2.7 and every time that the configuration management threw an error I chose to go ahead and install, which it would say was breaking the installation.

---

Originally posted by [teddybouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/581/teddybouch/) with karma: 320 on 2011-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0